# Python 2.7 mac MySQLdb installation

Tags: python, macos

I receive the following error when I run `python setup.py build` command in the terminal.
What am I doing wrong here, I thought MySQL was pre-insalled on Mac OS X, do I also need to download and install MySQL?

```
sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/Users/efet/Documents/workspace/kampuster/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "/Users/efet/Documents/workspace/kampuster/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

Comment: Whch version of OSX? mysql is not installed on Mountain Lion and might only be on Server versions - see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x/1448446#1448446) toinstall

Comment: I have 10.7.5, then I guess its not installed.

Comment: This is really annoying, I found out that I already installed a while ago so the link you shared wont help me

Comment: how did you install it - as the whole peorcess is complex it might be best to start from scratch

Comment: I re installed it today. Still not working. Documentation sucks big time with python, I will continue using .net.

Comment: The issue is not python but MySql? anyway we need to now what you have done to help you

Answer (score -3):

you probably need to install the development files, in Debian `mysql_config` is in the package `libmysqlclient-dev`.

Comment: Isnt Debian for linux? My operating system is Mac os x.

Comment: I know, but I don't know what's your package manager or how you install stuffs. Try to look at `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql-config` as pointed out in the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898750/installing-mysqldb-for-python-2-6-on-osx