# 404 error when using brew to install mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I tried to install mysql using brew and got the following error:

```
dyn-160-39-161-214:Cellar Bren$ brew install mysql
==> Downloading http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.19.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "mysql"
Download failed: http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.19.tar.gz
dyn-160-39-161-214:Cellar Brennan$ brew install mysql
==> Downloading http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.19.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "mysql"
Download failed: http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.19.tar.gz
```

I looked around and couldn't find any resources about this. To be frank I'm not sure its a fault on my side. I seem to be able to brew other things ok.

Comment: If you try and load `http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.19.tar.gz` in a browser directly you'll get the same "404 not found" error. Seems like that version of MySQL is no longer hosted at that location. Does  running `brew update` to get the latest formulas help?

Comment: Hello again Bren, try update brew first!