# Problems using MySQL with AWS Lambda in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to get up and running with AWS Lambda Python (beginner in Python btw) but having some problems with including MySQL dependency. I am trying to follow the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) on my Mac.

For step number 3, I am getting some problems with doing the command at the root of my project

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python -t /
```

Error:

> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
>       os.path.join(options.target_dir, item)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 292, in move
>       raise Error, "Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst
>   Error: Destination path '/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7.egg-info/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7.egg-info' already exists

I end up writing my following lambda function (works fine on my Mac), which is:

```
import MySQLdb

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   # Open database connection
   db = MySQLdb.connect(...)

   # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
   cursor = db.cursor()

   sql = "SELECT * FROM Users"

   try:
      # Execute the SQL command
      cursor.execute(sql)
      # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
      results = cursor.fetchall()
      for row in results:
         fname = row[0]
         lname = row[1]
         age = row[2]
         sex = row[3]
         income = row[4]
         # Now print fetched result
         print ("lname=%s" %(lname))
   except:
      print "Error: unable to fecth data"

   # disconnect from server
   db.close()
```

What I went on to do is go to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages and copying over the the MySQLdb folders/files that were downloaded when I did sudo pip install MySQL-python (without -t /) (I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here), to my lambda project, and then zipped the content along with the lambda_function.py and uploaded to AWS Lambda.

Then I get:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named MySQLdb

Grateful for any help and suggestions!

**EDIT**

Was able to do make sudo pip install MySQL-python -t /pathToProject work (thanks for the help in the comments) but now I get this when runing the lambda function:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /var/task/_mysql.so: invalid ELF header

I know that if I work on a Linux box, then it should work fine (as suggested by some people), but I am wondering if I can make it work from an OS X box.

Comment: What is the output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`? Why are you using the system python? Haven't you installed one in your `/usr/local` path with homebrew or macports? If not, you should. You will not need to use `sudo` for pip because it will be owned by your own user and won't be changing any system owned files. Also, it will be completely seperate from the python that your system depends on. It will also be a newer version, since it's from a repository.

Comment: If you don't have it, install homebrew with the `curl` instruction from  `http://brew.sh` and then run `brew install python` `pip install MySQLdb`. Verify that your python is in /usr/local/bin by running `which python` -- homebrew will have set your $PATH variable to look in `/usr/local/` to find the correct python.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, will use homebrew to install. Will keep you updated (btw I am a beginner in Python, so thank you for helping me ramp up)

Comment: Please check my edited question

Comment: mysql.so was most likely compiled  against a different version of python.

Comment: Padraic, can you suggest steps that would fix the versioning problem?

Comment: Can you not do your installation on the server? What service on aws are you actually using?

Comment: AWS Lambda, you can see in the question :)

Comment: Do you have access to a linux box?

Comment: Well I can use VirtualBox to launch one, but wondering if I can make it work on OS X :) But yes at the end, I might end up doing that to make it work.. seems to be much easier on Linux

Comment: I think the latest issue may well relate to the fact you are using a mac, I would suggest you try  using a linux box and that will at least rule someething out or confirm the cause of the issue.

Comment: Good idea, I agree! I will go ahead and try that :)

Comment: This is for nodejs but I imagine it also answers your question https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a use case like Lambda you'll be a lot happier using a pure python implementation like [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL).

It's a drop in replacement for MySQLdb that follows the [Python Database API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) specification. For most things like triggered Lambda events it will be just as fast.

I've used it in production a lot and it works great.

Comment: I get an error `ImportError: No module named MySQLdb` when I replace MySQLdb with PyMySQL for my sqlalchemy models

Comment: @systemjack : can you please let me know how you included pymysql in your lamda.

Comment: @Hussain We don't use sqlalchemy so I'm not sure about how to make that use pymysql. Here's some links that show basic usage: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-deployment-pkg.html, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html...You have to use pip to install it in your project directory/deployment package with -t option.

Comment: It worked with sqlalchemy. Thanks for the links by the way. I am actually using it for my Lambda only.

Comment: sqlalchemy documentation says they support pymysql http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html

Comment: @Hussain, would you mind sharing how could you make SQLAlchemy work with Lambda? Thanks

Comment: Why not use MySQLdb?

Answer (score 8):

## TLDR: Yes, you CAN use `mysqlclient` in AWS Lambda Python functions.

#### Here's one way - by creating your own AWS Lambda Layer for `mysqlclient` (i.e. `MySQLdb`).

> Then I get `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named MySQLdb`

> I know that if I work on a Linux box, then it should work fine (as suggested by some people), but I am wondering if I can make it work from an OS X box.

I too was facing the exact same error while trying to `import MySQLdb` in my AWS Lambda Python function.

After a lot of searching for a solution and not happy with using `pymysql` as a substitute (for performance and compatibility reasons), I ended up building my own [AWS Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) for `mysqlclient`. I could not find a "ready-made" layer for `mysqlclient` - not even at the awesome [KLayers project](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers). I am glad to share a GitHub repo with an example "ready-made" layer and an easy solution to build your own custom layer for your requirements that uses the recommended procedure by AWS.

[`mysqlclient`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) (MySQLdb) is a Python wrapper around a high-performance C implementation of the MySQL API. This makes it typically much faster than pure-python implementations such as `pymysql` in most cases (see [this list](https://github.com/nonbeing/mysqlclient-python3-aws-lambda#performance-comparison) for some examples), but it also brings some problems such as the one you are facing.

Since it is compiled against the `mysql-devel` package (e.g. a `.rpm` or `.deb` file provided by MySQL), `mysqlclient` is linked to a platform-specific binary such as `libmysqlclient.so` in order to work. In other words, the `libmysqlclient.so` from a Mac OS laptop (as an example) won't work in the AWS Lambda environment which uses some form of `Amazon Linux 2` as of this writing. You need a `libmysqlclient.so` compiled in and for the AWS Lambda environment (or as close to it as possible) for it to work in your AWS Lambda function.

A closely-simulated AWS-Lambda environment is available in the form of [Docker images from lambci](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda).

So to package an AWS-Lambda compatible `mysqlclient` you could:

- pull a suitable docker container such as `lambci/lambda:build-python3.8`
- import the [MySQL repo GPG key](https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql)
- install the [MySQL repo setup RPM](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/) so that `yum` can find and download other MySQL repo packages
- `yum install` the necessary dependencies such as the appropriate `mysql-devel` rpm for your use-case
- run `pip install mysqlclient` in the container
- zip the necessary `libmysqlclient.so` file and mysqlclient's python lib directories

This is more-or-less the officially-recommended procedure by AWS: see [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)
.

The zip thus created can be used to create a new AWS Lambda layer for `mysqlclient`. You can use this layer to readily use `mysqlclient` without any errors in your Lambda function.

After a lot of hair-pulling, I finally got the full procedure to work and automated it into a single script (`build.sh`) in [this GitHub project](https://github.com/nonbeing/mysqlclient-python3-aws-lambda). The code builds a `layer.zip` file that you can directly upload as a new AWS Lambda layer. The project currently builds for Python3.8 and MySQL server 8.0.x, but can be easily adapted to a different Python version and target MySQL version using the instructions and tools provided. There is also a ready-to-use `layer.zip` in the repo - in case you want to use `mysqlclient` against MySQL v8.0.x and in Python 3.8 (both tested) in your AWS Lambda function. Our production env uses SqlAlchemy which uses this MySqlClient Lambda layer and it's been working great for us.

After you configure your Lambda function to use a layer built as described (e.g. using the tools in the aforementioned repo), you can just `import MySQLdb` as usual in your Lambda function and get on with writing your real code:

```py
import MySQLdb

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'MySQLdb was successfully imported'
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Just update your lambda layer by uploading two packages:
- sqlalchemy
- PyMySQL (driver to use instead of mysqlclient)

Now update your driver url to "mysql+pymysql://...".

This makes you use pymysql driver which is compatible with Lambda environment for your existing environments.

Don't forget to set VPC endpoint for RDS. This keeps performance and security in check.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is mostly down to missing development packages. I think you will need the following:

sudo yum -y install mysql-devel

Comment: Ah sorry never had to this for my Mac but I did install the MySQLdb pip module successfully  on my Mac. Do you have mysql installed already on your Mac? If not then http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#macosx-dmg

Comment: Yep already installed... or else I couldn t have made it work locally :)

Answer (score 1):

AWS recently came out with a great solution for the issue of database drivers and database access in Lambda: the [Aurora Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html). The Data API tunnels SQL over HTTP using AWS standard auth. This bypasses the problems with compiling native code and using traditional database connection models in Lambda.

I ended up writing a DB-API compatible driver for it: [aurora-data-api](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/aurora-data-api) (and a [SQLAlchemy dialect](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/sqlalchemy-aurora-data-api) using it):

```
import aurora_data_api

cluster_arn = "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster:my-aurora-serverless-cluster"
secret_arn = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:MY_DB_CREDENTIALS"
with aurora_data_api.connect(aurora_cluster_arn=cluster_arn, secret_arn=secret_arn, database="my_db") as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables")
        print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: How would I use this with Django?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use Amazon Linux instance to build your python packages and then to include them in your Lambda deployment package. Check out [this excellent article](http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html) about how to do it. Packages mentioned in the article are different from the one you need, but similarly it helped me to build psycopg2 and pymssql for my lambdas.

Comment: Interesting! Will try that out as soon as i m back from vacation. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Lambda -> Layers (add new layer)

download zip of pymysql from https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/#files

when you download, unzip then rename parent folder to "python" then rezip (should be python/{where the pysqlfiles are}

add a layer to Lambda called 'pymysql' and upload that zip

then in Lambda function import pymysql

Answer (score -1):

Using [lambda-docker](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) you can set up and test your Lambda functions without access to a like-wise Linux environment.

To set up your lambda, use a [lambda-docker](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) build image to run a detached docker container and run `pip install <package>` commands on the container. Then export the container, grab the installed packages under `usr/lib`, and place them in your AWS Lambda package.

Then you can test for compatibility by running your lambda on a lambda-docker image. If it works, go forth and upload to AWS Lambda with confidence.

```
docker run -d -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-python2.7 tail -f /dev/null 

docker ps

docker exec 0c55aae443e6 pip install pandas

docker exec 0c55aae443e6 pip install sqlalchemy

docker exec 0c55aae443e6 pip freeze

docker exec 0c55aae443e6 python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"

docker container export -o lambda_ready_container 0c55aae443e6
```

Answer (score -5):

The problem happens similarly in my Ubuntu installer, the real problem is because it is pending on a mysql client connector driver. So the solution is install Mysql client-dev package to make MySQL-python happy(to make use of the client library).

```
# Ubuntu only(or setup vm for ubuntu inside your mac) 
# Three dependencies for MySQL python recompilation 
sudo apt-get install python-dev  libssl-dev

#Now the mysql client-dev  
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

# If you like mariadb client
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

## For MAC

```
# try this first
fink install mysql-unified-dev

# or this if above fail. 
brew install mysql
# you must add this to your user profile startup if you use brew 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

You can get similar answer here : [Mac OS X - EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459386/mac-os-x-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found)

Then try the pip install.

I don't recommend anyone use "sudo pip". You should setup Virtualenv and virtualwrapper for your python development, that allow you to pip without sudo. And it is easier to isolate and test new deployment. (although it doesn't fix the mysqlclient-dev library issue)