# Install part of pandas module

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pip

Pandas is a pretty bulky module, hence I do not wish to install it in its entirity. Only the ones I'll be using in my codes.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import pivot_table
from pandas import read_csv
```

How can I pip install only these packages?

```
pip install ?
```

Using Python 2.7 on Windows.

**EDIT:**
Space is an issue for me. Pandas is a bulky module and is difficult to import onto `aws lambda`

Comment: Is space really that big of a concern for you?

Comment: If you are using `pandas` for data analysis, which is its main use, space for this library should not be an issue.

Comment: if space is _that_ much of a concern you probably shouldn't be writing Excel files...

Comment: @user4343502 Yes, please check the edit for the reason.

Comment: @jpp Please check edit for the reason.

Comment: It may help to ask about installing pandas on AWS Lambda, instead of asking about a partial installation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054976/pandas-aws-lambda

Comment: Also you said on Windows, AWS Lambda is not Windows, it's serverless

Answer (score 1):

This is not officially supported by `pandas`.  The pandas documentation ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html)) make no mention of how to install some parts of the module but not others.  This is probably because of how tightly coupled the functions and modules are.