# How to create AWS Lambda deployment package that uses mysql-connector-python on Mac OS?

Tags: python, pip, mysql-connector, aws-lambda

I need to fetch some data from MySQL database inside AWS Lambda function. How to achieve this? I already tried **pip install mysql-connector-python -t ~/lambda-dir/**. It does not work on my Mac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems using MySQL with AWS Lambda in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763380/problems-using-mysql-with-aws-lambda-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Creating a deployment package for AWS Lambda for Python is a little different procedure on Mac than Linux. First, I had to create setup.cfg file inside the package directory had to write this on setup.cfg file:

```
[install]
prefix=
```

Another thing is that, I had to use

`pip install mysql-connector-python-rf -t ~/lambda_folder`

instead of

`pip install mysql-connector-python -t ~/lambda_folder`