# Am I required to use Amazon Linux on AWS lambda?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pandas, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to zip python 2.7 code with pandas and cassandra libraries on my local windows 7 computer. From the anaconda prompt I did `pip install -t 'folder location'` for both pandas and cassandra and I zipped the contents - not the folder. I am getting the error `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`. However, pandas included numpy as a dependency and it is in the zip file. [zip file contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuCp6.png)

I researched this isssue, and found [Pandas & AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054976/pandas-aws-lambda) the marked answer says: *All static packages have to be compiled on an EC2 Amazon Linux instance.*

This article that was referenced in another question [Problems using MySQL with AWS Lambda in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763380/problems-using-mysql-with-aws-lambda-in-python/43766512#43766512) says to *use EC2 Amazon linux and virtualenv*: http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html

**Does this mean I am having problems because I am using my local windows 7 computer, is it required to use EC2 Amazon linux?**

Comment: What happens with you do use an EC2 Amazon Linux instance?

Comment: Can't you just `git checkout` on the linux instance instead of zipping it and emailing it to yourself?

Comment: @Loaf I don't have an Amazon Linux EC2 instance provisioned. I guess I will work on that. Jim - I am zipping it and uploading to S3 and then bringing it into AWS Lambda.

Comment: @red79phoenix you should be able to utilize the Free Tier for this, so there will be no charges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer to my question is Yes, you do have to use EC2 Amazon Linux. I found this post on the AWS forum regarding the Cassandra-Driver library: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=247496

I was a little unsure about how to do this but I found a great tutorial from AWS: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html

I followed the instructions and created a virtualenv and downloaded everything - seems to be working. I got past that error but now it is unable to download from S3, I will create a new thread for that.