# My django can't runserver on mac

Tags: mysql, django

Hi all and thanks for taking time to help.

I am a front-end developer and newbie on the Django project.

I am trying to config a project on my Mac.

My colleague helped me to install the virtual environment but it an error still be there when I try to run the server of my project(Hobbit is the name of my project).

```
(env) ➜  Hobbit git:(feature/sell_system_main) ✗ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so

  Reason: image not found
```

So I try to reinstall mysql by `pip install mysql-python` and result is

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mysql-python in /Users/liao/workspace/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

It seems that I have installed mysql in virtual environment.

Now I am confused what is the problem. Mysql or Django?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30979099/2932244) might help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459386/mac-os-x-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found

Comment: Install mysql devels

Comment: Did you install mysql-python in the same environment as Django ?