# Unable to install MySQL driver for Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

On running `pip install MySQL-python` I get following error:

```
llecting MySQL-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 202kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-fJr7Jp/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

I am using OSX and MySQL is installed with MAMP

Comment: you should put the mysql binaries in your path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459386/mac-os-x-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178292/pip-install-mysql-python-fails-with-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found

Comment: This is how I added `export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config:$PATH"` but it is not working

Comment: you just need the bin, path takes directories.

Comment: @pvg Awesome, it worked. Thanks!