# python setup.py egg_info error mysqlclient

Tags: python, django, macos, mysql-python

I just started learning Python using Django and I just seemed to be stuck at the same place for 3 days, every time I try to run the following command in my terminal using Pycharm (Yep, I am using a Mac) I get the below error:

Command: pip install mysqlclient

Error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/private/var/folders/3z/_xzmzzh90z9dj90cb70p3q0c0000gn/T/pip-build-c7mudszc/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
metadata, options = get_config()
File "/private/var/folders/3z/_xzmzzh90z9dj90cb70p3q0c0000gn/T/pip-build-c7mudszc/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
(venv) Mervins-MacBook-Pro:untitled mervinkobola$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/private/var/folders/3z/_xzmzzh90z9dj90cb70p3q0c0000gn/T/pip-build-w_jamo3b/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
metadata, options = get_config()
File "/private/var/folders/3z/_xzmzzh90z9dj90cb70p3q0c0000gn/T/pip-build-w_jamo3b/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
(venv) Mervins-MacBook-Pro:untitled mervinkobola$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/private/var/folders/3z/_xzmzzh90z9dj90cb70p3q0c0000gn/T/pip-build-xefx4qk7/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
metadata, options = get_config()
File "/private/var/folders/3z/_xzmzzh90z9dj90cb70p3q0c0000gn/T/pip-build-xefx4qk7/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
File "/private/var/folders/3z/_xzmzzh90z9dj90cb70p3q0c0000gn/T/pip-build-xefx4qk7/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
OSError: mysql_config not found

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3z/_xzmzzh90z9dj90cb70p3q0c0000gn/T/pip-build-xefx4qk7/mysqlclient/
```

Please help me understand whats going on and how I can solve it. Above all I can't seem to run the following :

python manage.py migrate (as I haven't installed mysqlclient)

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You might find [this answer useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25491082/113962) (ignore the `pip install MySQL-Python` and stick with `pip install mysqlclient`). Note that if you're just learning Python and Django, you may find it easier to stick with sqlite3 instead of MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your response, well I've already used MySQL, and it seems to connecting successfully, I just cant run the following command "python manage.py migrate" for my tables, it will ask me if I've installed mysqlclient (even when I go to my virtual env and try there without using my command, it still gives an error), is there pehaps a quick fix, and this is on mac using pycharm?

Comment: The quickest fix is to use sqlite3, which doesn't require any additional packages to be installed. If you want to use Django with MySQL, then you need to install `mysqlclient` in your virtual environment. The answer I linked to has some suggestions for installing it on a Mac which will hopefully help, but I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use mysqlite 3, hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the variable `mysql_config` is set in the `Terminal` but not in `PyCharm` so this is why you're getting this error.

### The solution is:

1. run the `PyCharm` from the terminal with this command:

   `/Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm`
2. After that (in `PyCharm`) install the packages you need (probably they are in your `requirements.txt`, for example the `mysqlclient`),
3. `Close` the program and `re-open`
4. Now it should have all the packages installed properly