# MySQL running using Xampp but pip installing mysqlclient throws error EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-python

I have installed XAMPP on my mac OSX that have mysql MariaDB running, now from terminal I can run MySQL but if I try to install mysqlclient I get the error saying :

```
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/43/m1qv9zf53q19sqh6h9kg9pz80000gn/T/pip-install-7vpJZR/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 28, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

I tried following this thread [Mac OS X - EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25459386/3311276) before posting it here, but I think since my MySQL is installed by XAMPP the configuration they are talking about in that thread does not apply to my case of problem.