# How do you edit MySQL_Config?

Tags: python, mysql

The docs at https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/ say that there's a known macOS issue, and to fix it you should edit mysql-Config. There doesn't seem to be a file named mySQL_Config.

The command mysql-config does work but I can't find the source of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972734/7316502 looks like it might be what you're running into -- has some good, detailed instructions if so.

Answer (score 0):

On most linux systems (which you Mac is not) it is in. /etc/my.conf

But your Mac (or at least mine) has it in

```
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

You can edit this with vi or anything else you like. I suggest you make a copy/backup of it first however.