# Big Sur clang "invalid version" error due to MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

Tags: python, macos

I assume due to the fact Big Sur is sparkling new hotfixes for the new OS have not yet happen. When attempting to install modules that use `clang` for compilation, the following error is thrown:

```
clang: error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0'
```

Currently running:

- Mac OS Big Sur, 11.0 Beta
- **Intel** CPU (i386)
- Python 3.8.0 installed via `pyenv`

Multiple modules have `clang` dependencies, and so it seems this error is quite common. An example:

```
pip install multidict
```

Installing older versions of Command Line Tools (e.g. 11.5) does not work as well.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Figure out the issue on my end.

Previously I had installed `XCode` from the App Store (11.7) and set its SDKs as my default:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/
```

However, it seems this come with an unsupported version of `clang`:

```
  λ clang --version
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Setting the `xcode-select` to the latest version via:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

> **EDIT (11/15/2020)**
>
> You might receive an error when attempting the above change:
>
> `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'`
>
> To fix this, you must install the latest Command Line Tools from the official Apple website [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode). At the time of writting this edit, I installed the **Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.3 beta**.

Changes `clang` to a working version:

```
  λ clang --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

The built-in Big Sur SDK is version `10.15`, which seems to work without an issue:

```
  λ ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs
MacOSX.sdk      MacOSX10.15.sdk
```

After the switch, `multidict` was installed successfully.

```
  λ pip install multidict
Collecting multidict
  Downloading multidict-4.7.6-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (48 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 48 kB 589 kB/s
Installing collected packages: multidict
Successfully installed multidict-4.7.6
```

Further investigation seems to indicate this is a design choice by Apple ([source](https://twitter.com/jeremyhu/status/1285230460402987008?s=20)):

[image]

Therefore, ensuring your SDK is the default out-of-the-box as opposed to XCode's new SDK should be enough for the system to switch context when needed (and seems to work fine with `pip`+`clang`).

Answer (score 88):

I would like to extend @Felipe excellent answer; *if* it doesn't work even with running

```
>>> softwareupdate --all --install --force
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
No updates are available.
```

...following the wisdom of the "homebrew doctor" solves it, i.e. remove and reinstall:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Great find. Thank you for reminding me to update my answer- since then, Apple now requires users to install the latest version of the Xcode Command Line Tools from their website. Updated for anyone else looking into the answer.

Comment: The second part of the answer fixed it for me.

Comment: the sceond part worked for me but then I had to re-switch the xcode-select

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Comment: You're a lifesaver! I dunno why it was so hard to find the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 27):

I had already removed and reinstalled xtools CLI, but the error persisted..

All I needed to do was

```
export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1
```

then the error went away.

"SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT" is an environment variable which macOS utilities and 3rd-parties use to determine how they behave when running on newer versions of macOS, i.e. to allow backwards compatibility or not. It is often used by devs and does not guarantee an app will function normally.

its value ranges from unset, 0 (disable) and 1 (enable). Default value varies across OS version. While with little impact, it is good practice to confirm/backup your system's existing setting before changing this value.

Comment: I was using `pipenv install` then it spit a ton of error and warning in the console, then after set this, it works like charm and all the dependencies are installed/resolved smoothly. This saved my day! Thanks

Comment: @user8076929 your edit is very useful. Does that information come from somewhere online (e.g. can a link/source be included?)

Answer (score 24):

in my case I had to remove `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and re-install command line tools

```
% sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
% sudo xcode-select --install
% clang --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Thanks! I had clang 11.0.3, but macOS "Software Update" did not update it. Deleting and reinstalling worked.

Comment: god bless you!!!

Comment: If you installed Xcode, `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` is preferred to `sudo xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 5):

In my case removing CLT and LLVM and setting XCode just compiled.

```
% sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
% sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
% brew uninstall llvm # if installed via brew
% clang --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

gcc and g++ now compiling without any error.

Answer (score 3):

For my case, to be safe, I renamed the existing directory and reinstalled the latest one. The "clang" build error is gone right after the update.

Before:

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Action:

```
sudo mv /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools.old
sudo xcode-select --install
```

After:

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.27.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

macOS Monterey 12.3.2 failed to install a new version of python.

```
$ pyenv install 3.8.4
```

found it was due to a bug in the latest version of Monterey as MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET was previously set to 12.3.

Fixed it by setting MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.3.0

```
% pyenv install 3.8.4
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.4.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.4/Python-3.8.4.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.4...
patching file Misc/NEWS.d/next/Build/2021-10-11-16-27-38.bpo-45405.iSfdW5.rst
patching file configure
patching file configure.ac
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.3.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/5r/61nxx8hs53x6hhzm_r86jhjrq0r6qq/T/python-build.20220504193655.2344
Results logged to /var/folders/5r/61nxx8hs53x6hhzm_r86jhjrq0r6qq/T/python-build.20220504193655.2344.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/5r/61nxx8hs53x6hhzm_r86jhjrq0r6qq/T/python-build.20220504193655.2344/Python-3.8.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

After fix:

```
 % pyenv install 3.8.4
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.4.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.4/Python-3.8.4.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.4...
patching file Misc/NEWS.d/next/Build/2021-10-11-16-27-38.bpo-45405.iSfdW5.rst
patching file configure
patching file configure.ac
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installed Python-3.8.4 to /Users/{USER}/.pyenv/versions/3.8.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different issue, while trying to build Qt WebEngine 6.5 on an iMac m1. For me, the error was

```
error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='
```

I tried what was suggested, but while it had fixed this issue, the following steps failed because Qt was complaining about having a Command Line Tools instance only, unable to find Xcode.

I solved by simply setting a value to it :

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11
```

Context : iMac m1 (arm64 chip), macOS Ventura 13.4, XCode 14.3, Qt Webengine 6.5.1