# How to change python's version on WING 101 on a Mac?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a project with python 3.8.6. However, I want to change python's version that I am using to 3.5.3. How can I do this? I'm on a Mac.

I have tried installing python 3.5.3 with the installer from the python downloads website but after it installs and I run python3.5 on my shell, it says

```
zsh: killed     python3.5
```

If I run `python3.8` on the shell, it works, but I want the 3.5 version so I can then get the `sys.executable` to then change the path in Wing.

I've also tried pyenv with homebrew but it fails when it tries to install. It says

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.0.1 using python-build 20180424)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Pyenv is definitely the way to go for installing multiple versions of Python. When installing pyenv fails, is that all it says, or does it print out any more information?

Comment: this is what it says when i try to install python 3.5.3 with penv:


```none
BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.0.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/_w/jxrcdv_90bj_5mw0_3tndbd40000gn/T/python-build.20210102141244.726
Results logged to /var/folders/_w/jxrcdv_90bj_5mw0_3tndbd40000gn/T/python-build.20210102141244.726.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Conda.
Installation: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html

To create environments and switch between them:

```
conda create -n 3.5.3 python=3.5.3
conda activate 3.5.3
conda env list
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for macOS 11 is still an [open issue](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1737) for pyenv. It's also been [asked about before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839538/pyenv-wont-install-python-3-on-mac-os-11) here on Stack Overflow, though due to installing a different Python version, this might not be 100% a duplicate.

One solution that seems to be working for people is that posted in [this blog post](https://dev.to/kojikanao/install-python-3-8-0-via-pyenv-on-bigsur-4oee):

> **Step 1 Align command-line tools**
>
> - Open Xcode-beta.app
> - Go to Preference > Locations
> - Select the right version of command-line tools
>
> **Step 2 Install python**
>
> In this case, I installed 3.8.0. If you want to install a different version, you will need to change the version in the following command.
>
> ```sh
> CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" pyenv install --patch 3.8.0 < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)
> ```

You may also need to make sure you have the following installed:

```sh
brew install zlib bzip2
```