# Error installing Pyobjc on macOS 11.0 Big Sur

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, pyobjc

I'm getting an error when trying to install the [pyobjc](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/) library in a virtual environment on Big Sur. The installation errors out claiming that it "*Cannot determine SDK version*." I've done some digging, and it looks like this error is triggered by an exception in [this flow](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/blob/3a858a797c0667d48db3ac83a6446e918b5e2966/pyobjc-core/Tools/pyobjc_setup.py#L244).

Here's the beginning of the error:

```
Building wheel for pyobjc-core (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/me/Desktop/Projects/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-qixc6c89/pyobjc-core/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-qixc6c89/pyobjc-core/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/tmp/pip-wheel-c0phpdjv
       cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-qixc6c89/pyobjc-core/
```

And here's the end of the error:

```
    copying PyObjCTest/test_specialtypecodes_methdef.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.9/PyObjCTest
    running build_ext
    Cannot determine SDK version
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/me/Desktop/Projects/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-qixc6c89/pyobjc-core/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-qixc6c89/pyobjc-core/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-l_v97344/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/me/Desktop/Projects/env/include/site/python3.9/pyobjc-core Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've tried reinstalling Xcode developer tools to no avail, as I thought this might refresh the SDK references. Any help would be much appreciated.

- Trying to install pyobjc version **7.0**
- Python version: **3.9.0**, **3.8.2** (tried on both and neither work)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big Sur clang "invalid version" error due to MACOSX\_DEPLOYMENT\_TARGET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972113/big-sur-clang-invalid-version-error-due-to-macosx-deployment-target)

Comment: @Felipe I don't think so. I ran `clang --version' and I got the exact same output as what you said worked for you (version 12.0.0, etc.) The one difference for me is that in my SDKs directory, I have three entries instead of two: _MacOSX.sdk_, _MacOSX10.15.sdk_, and _MacOSX11.0.sdk_. _MacOSX.sdk_ is only an alias that redirects to _MacOSX11.0.sdk_, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue should be resolved by now. So running `pip install pyobjc` should be working again as expected (tested for pyobjc-**7.0.1** and python**3.9.0**).

If not, you can set the SDK temporarily for the current session and build it from scratch with:

```sh
SDKROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk pip wheel pyobjc-core
```

(If it doesn't work, check what SDKs you have installed. It worked for me with `MacOSX10.15`, just run `ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/` and see what's available. You need the Xcode CLI tools for this.)
After that just run `pip install pyobjc` again to install the rest of pyobjc.

For some framework addons you might have to set cflags specifically with:

```sh
SDKROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk \
    CFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk" \
    pip wheel pyobjc-framework-cocoa
```

Again just switch `MacOSX10.14.sdk` with a 10.X SDK on your system.

There's more information on [this related GitHub issue](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/issues/333) from which i shamelessly stole this solution from [@hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling) on s.o. <3

Comment: Yep, just ran `pip install pyobjc` and it went through without any issues 

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this, managed to solve it by removing the symlink and all SDKs other than 11.0 from `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs`. Not entirely sure what this does for system stability or other software, but the `pip install pyobjc` did actually finish.

I do not claim to be an expert on MacOS development, so YMMV.

Comment: I'm hesitant to try this only because as you pointed out I don't know what the side-effects of removing the other SDKs/symlink might be.

Answer (score 0):

PyObjC should install using binary wheels (without compiling). Please file an issue in GitHub when it doesn't, and include information about your Python installation (such as how Python was installed).