# Can't install jupyter (or jupyter lab) w/ pipenv & big sur

Tags: python, jupyter, pipenv, macos-big-sur

Not sure if this is a Big Sur thing or so... Set up an env through pipenv specifying python 3.8 (otherwise numpy etc. broke). Getting an error w/ argon2 when I try installing jupyter (i.e. `pipenv install jupyter`); is this a known Big Sur thing, or would you have any thoughts?

[image: my error]

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you end up resolving this?

Comment: @williamrfry I had in my logs a clang error and eventually the same error as above mentioned. In my case, this solved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64838849/4033690

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by installing `libffi` and `mercurial` via homebrew. After doing that, I was still running into issues before realizing that homebrew was downloading bottles for its Python 3.9 distribution (not Big Sur's system-wide Python 3 version, 3.8). Once I ran the following, everything installed correctly: `` pipenv install --python `which python3.9` install jupyterlab ``.

Although I installed both homebrew packages, I believe I only needed to install `libffi` for it to work. In a perfect world, homebrew would install it for the system-installed Python version but c'este la vie. Everything's working now.