# clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=11.2'

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur

I am currently on Mac OSX Big Sur 11.2.3. Whenever I run the command:

```sh
g++-10 -o project0 project0.cpp -lm -fopenmp
```

I get the following error:

```sh
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=11.2'
```

I realized that this may be due to the fact that I'm on Big Sur 11.2.3 but I was told that this should not be an issue. I've tried many things already such as reinstalling gcc doing `brew install gcc` and so forth to no avail. At this point, I'm very unsure on what to do. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big Sur clang "invalid version" error due to MACOSX\_DEPLOYMENT\_TARGET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972113/big-sur-clang-invalid-version-error-due-to-macosx-deployment-target)

Comment: I used this answer and it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65094410

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem while trying to install fiona. You are correct it is due to Big Sur, as you can see in this [article](https://emilwypych.com/2020/11/23/pyenv-problem-macosx_deployment_target11-0/?cn-reloaded=1)

Follow it and it should sort out the issue. Note, I had to uninstall Command Line tools and re-install it as outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617452/how-to-update-xcode-from-command-line).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when I tried to compile a library with clang-9 on an up-to-date system, with clang-9 installed via homebrew:

```
clang-9: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=12.6'
```

Updating xcode command line tools doesn't help here, since I actually want / have to use the old compiler. Setting the following environment variable for the build solved the issue:

```
export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different issue, while trying to build Qt WebEngine 6.5 on an iMac m1. For me, the error was

```
error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='
```

I tried what was suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64838849/4759678), but while it had fixed this issue, the following steps failed because Qt was complaining about having a Command Line Tools instance only, unable to find Xcode.

I solved by simply setting a value to it :

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11
```

Context : iMac m1 (arm64 chip), macOS Ventura 13.4, XCode 14.3, Qt Webengine 6.5.1