# Cmake error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=12.5'

Tags: cmake, macos-ventura

I am trying to compile a program with `cmake` on a Mac (M2) running Ventura 13.4. It fails with the following error:

```
The C compiler

    "/Users/me/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

Somewhere in the error message I see that the compiler throws the error `clang-10: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=12.5'`.

In my `CMakeError.log` file, I see the following clue:

```
The output was:
1
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried removing and reinstalling Command Line Tools as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65094410), and have also tried enabling the `SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT` environment variable as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65245427). The error persists after doing this.

Is there something else that I can try?